# What do you do with the key?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I got a key somehow and I don't know what it is for. What does it unlock?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use it to open a chest. If you don't know what chest I'm talking about, try burying yourself in the sand (in-game sand).